# How do I finish the loop and import the text file

Tags: sql, text-files

This is the code wherein I need to define the path of the file in the path.Inside the "string path" i have something like this.

(C:\folder\text.txt)

```
string path = @"C:\path.txt";
StreamReader str = new StreamReader(path);
string datasample;

while ((datasample = str.ReadLine()) != null)
      {
      }
```

what I need to do is to import the txt file into SQL table.here is my code for importing which works fine.

```
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(Global_Variables.filename.ToString());
             DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                DataRow row;
                dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Reports"));

                while (!sr.EndOfStream)
                {
                    string value = sr.ReadLine();
                    if ((value.Length != 0) && (value != ""))
                    {
                        row = dt.NewRow();
                        row[0] = value;
                        dt.Rows.Add(row);
                    }
                }
                SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(Global_Variables.con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
                bc.DestinationTableName = "tbl_WinApps_ApprovedExpReports";
                bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
                Global_Variables.con.Open();
                bc.WriteToServer(dt);
                bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 120;
                bc.Close();
                Global_Variables.con.Close();
```

I cant seem to join the two codes together.pls help :(

Comment: Have you tried string path = @"C:\path.txt"; StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path); instead of your first line in the second script?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you already loop through the file using the StreamReader so you could do something like this:

```
string path = File.ReadAllText(@"C:\path.txt");
string line = "";
StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(path);
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
DataRow row;
dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Reports"));

while ((line = sr.readLine()) != null)
{
    if ((line.Length != 0) && (line != ""))
    {
        row = dt.NewRow();
        row[0] = line;
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
}

SqlBulkCopy bc = new SqlBulkCopy(Global_Variables.con.ConnectionString, SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock);
bc.DestinationTableName = "tbl_WinApps_ApprovedExpReports";
bc.BatchSize = dt.Rows.Count;
Global_Variables.con.Open();
bc.WriteToServer(dt);
bc.BulkCopyTimeout = 120;
bc.Close();
Global_Variables.con.Close();
```

Comment: I already done that,the problem with that is that it only loops once. the adding of new rows will not be finished until the end of file.only 1 line is imported to SQL

Comment: it still doesnt..what i want is to locate and process the text file INSIDE my string path..on what is written inside the "C:\path.txt"

Comment: what happens when i run the program is.. it literally imports the value inside the @"C:\path.txt" which is wrong.

Comment: it works! but it only imported ONE(1) row.it has a hundreds of rows :(

Comment: i think it doesnt loop through all the rows thats why it returns only one row?

Comment: its my problem since morning.cant seem to find a way to fix it.